# Tensorflow - String processing in Dataset API

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have `.txt` files in a directory of format `<text>\t<label>`. I am using the `TextLineDataset` API to consume these text records:

```
filenames = ["/var/data/file1.txt", "/var/data/file2.txt"]

dataset = tf.contrib.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames)

dataset = dataset.flat_map(
    lambda filename: (
        tf.contrib.data.TextLineDataset(filename)
        .map(_parse_data)))

def _parse_data(line):   
    line_split = tf.string_split([line], '\t')
    features = {"raw_text": tf.string(line_split.values[0].strip().lower()),
                "label": tf.string_to_number(line_split.values[1], 
                    out_type=tf.int32)}
    parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(line, features)
    return parsed_features["raw_text"], raw_features["label"]
```

I would like to do some string cleaning/processing on the raw_text feature. When I try to run  `line_split.values[0].strip().lower()`, I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'strip'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The object `lines_split.values[0]` is a [`tf.Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor) object representing the 0th split from `line`. It is not a Python string, and so it does not have a `.strip()` or `.lower()` method. Instead you will have to apply TensorFlow operations to the tensor to perform the conversion.

TensorFlow currently doesn't have very many [string operations](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/string_ops), but you can use the [`tf.py_func()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func) op to run some Python code on a `tf.Tensor`:

```
def _parse_data(line):
    line_split = tf.string_split([line], '\t')

    raw_text = tf.py_func(
        lambda x: x.strip().lower(), line_split.values[0], tf.string)

    label = tf.string_to_number(line_split.values[1], out_type=tf.int32)

    return {"raw_text": raw_text, "label": label}
```

Note that there are a couple of other problems with the code in the question:

- Don't use [`tf.parse_single_example()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/parse_single_example). This op is only used for parsing `tf.train.Example` protocol buffer strings; you do not need to use it when parsing text, and you can return the extracted features directly from `_parse_data()`.
- Use [`dataset.map()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.4/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map) instead of [`dataset.flat_map()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.4/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#flat_map). You only need to use `flat_map()` when the result of your mapping function is a `Dataset` object (and hence the return values need to be *flattened* into a single dataset). You must use `map()` when the result is one or more `tf.Tensor` objects.

Comment: Thank you for providing some clarity here. I had been trying to use `py_func` but was encountering some errors. Your code works from me. Also, I've decided to convert my `.txt` data to `TFRecord` format. For future reference, should I use `python` to intergize my data before using `tensorflow`, or are there good patterns for doing all of this in `tf`. Right now, I use `python` with a `VocabularyProcessor` initialized with my self-built `CategoricalVocabulary`

Comment: For anyone coming across this answer, note that a fair number of string operations have been recently introduced in TensorFlow under the namespace [`tf.strings`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/strings). The transformation in this question in particular is still a bit complicated, because `regex_replace`, based on [re2](https://github.com/google/re2), does not support converting to lowercase, but at least you can do the stripping part.